# How to read properties from kafka connect configuration in custom SMT?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have setup debezium mysql source connector to capture mysql change data. I have also implemented a Custom Filter using SMT custom transformation.

I want to access some configs from the connector configuration. I have tried several things but no luck.

Eg  Config.
{ "name": "inventory-connector", "config": { "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector", "tasks.max": "1", "database.hostname": "mysql", "database.port": "3306", "database.user": "debezium", "database.password": "dbz", "database.server.id": "184054", "database.server.name": "dbserver1", "database.include.list": "inventory", "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.inventory" } }

I want to access "database.hostname" inside my SMT.
public class CustomFilter<S extends ConnectRecord> implements Transformation, Configurable {......)

TIA.